# apply multiple columns division in the same R markdown page

Tags: r, r-markdown, multiple-columns, sections

I want to divide my Rmarkdown document like in picture. One column for the first section then two columns in the other sections.

used `\onecolumn` and  `\twocolumn` but each section is created in a single page. Is there a solution to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I wish we have another answer to this question helping to get rid of page brakes after `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/10.1175/1520-0450%281994%29033%3C0003%3AAPMTFE%3E2.0.CO%3B2) has been published in a journal of the AMS. Fortunately, the `rticle` package supports the AMS journals. I use the standard template as generated by RStudio, change `layout` in the YAML header and use `fancyhdr` to redefine the pagestyle:

```
layout: twocol
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - '`\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}`{=latex}'
```

I then get the following result:

[image]

As an alternative, you could try to adapt the `revtex` LaTeX class as used by the APS.

Note: I am using a quite recent version of `pandoc`, which makes [the quoting of LaTeX complicated](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4253). With older versions of `pandoc` you might get away without the quoting.