# Change sections from two columns to one column in the same R markdown page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, multiple-columns

I want to write a document in two columns but I have a big graphic that I want to insert it in all the entire page like below:

[image]

Using \onecolum and `\twocolumn` in R markdown generate always empty pages in the changed pats..

Is there a solution to get rid of empty pages or to make those changing without generating them from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can build on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419920/8416610): In order to have a "standard article layout" with a wide abstract and two column text, I suggested to use the AMS template from the `rticle` package. This uses the LaTeX class `ametsoc.cls` which in turn uses `multicol.sty` to support two column layout. Now `multicol.sty` supports a simple way to have page-wide figures (or tables): Just use the starred environment instead of the normal one:

```
\begin{figure*}
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.pdf}}
  \caption{This figure environment will span the the page.}
\end{figure*}
```